# Facebook Graph API can't fetch all of my tagged photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote a python script to fetch all my photos on facebook using api v2.10.

```
api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1'
photo_url = '/me/photos'
params = {'fields': 'album,images', 'limit': 10000, 'access_token' : user_token}
r = requests.get(api_url + photo_url, params = params)
```

I am using user_token with the following permissions user_photos, user_friends, user_posts, public_profile but it only downloaded a few dozens photos out of a couple hundred of my photos.

By default /me/photos should get photos edge includes all photos a person has been tagged in per the documentation. I am not sure why so few has been retrieved.
I notice I have some my own uploaded photos and  some photos tagged by friends.

Comment: You can not just use a ridiculously high `limit` value and hope to get everything in one go that way; the `limit` parameter is limited itself. You need to paginate through the results (see chapter on basic API usage.)

Comment: @CBroe, I forgot to mention i paginate the results until there's there's no more "next" returned so I have looped through the results.

Comment: I noticed some tagged pictures owned by certain friends were never downloaded, for those pictures i took the photo id from my facebook page and paste it in to the API explorer as a test, it will return an error that it doesn't exists or i don't have permission. It leads me to think there's some privacy setting on their end which doesn't permit me to download them through the API. I think that also explain why a lot of the IFTTT recipes for auto downloading tagged photos didn't work for me either.